# WPF Progress bar

Tags: wpf

WPF: I have a Problem in Progressbar i want it to show when the operation is not finished and when my operation is finished it will hide. Please show me understandable example so i can apply it to my work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: WPF has nothing to do with ASP.NET. Don't misuse tags.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that in different scenarios.

1. using triggers, (I'd prefer that)

   ```
   <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Margin="10,107,232,168" Value="0" Name="progr">
       <ProgressBar.Resources>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value}" Value="100">
                       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </ProgressBar.Resources>
   </ProgressBar>
   ```
2. Using converters

   ```
   <Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <delWpf:VisibilityConverter x:Key="conv"/>
   </Grid.Resources>
       <ProgressBar Name="prog2" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
          Value="{Binding CurrentIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
   </Grid>
   ```

and converter

```
    public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Math.Abs((double)value - 100) < 0.001 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can u give me a sample that when the function is still reading by the program the progressbar will not stop and when the function is stop the progress bar will hide. .because thats the exact situation I have. . thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understood you. Do you want to show progressbar when function starts and hide it when function ends? if so, you'll have smth like that: 
        private void RefreshData()
        {
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            //...
            progressBar.Value = 100;
        }. But that doesn't make much sense, cuz you can control visibility here than. Explain in more details please

Comment: I just want to show the progressbar when the operation is not completed and hide it when the operation is completed. . sorry if you cant understand me but Thank you for time.

Comment: hey Artiom my error is "delWpf" in this code                     <Grid.Resources>
    <delWpf:VisibilityConverter x:Key="conv"/>
</Grid.Resources>

Comment: it should be alias to the namespace where is your converter is

Answer (score 1):

You might use Extended WPF Toolkit which has a BusyIndicator control,

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator

Samples are included in the download.

For your information, Microsoft introduces BusyIndicator in Silverlight first (but fails to ship one for WPF) as a replacement of progress bar.